# Customizing a microbial network visualized using plot_network in R

Tags: r, network-analysis

So I am able to plot the network using a phyloseq object as the input. I have really like my output (see image) but I am wondering, is it possible to 1st, change the label sizes for "OTUX". The second thing I would like to do is change the color palette used, but keep the color application based phyla. I looked at this documentation, but it doesnt mention any way to accomplish this.

Documentation: https://rdrr.io/bioc/phyloseq/man/plot_network.html

Current visualization: [Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwDN8.jpg)

Code:

```
## Network Analysis ##
# set seed for reproducability #
set.seed(1)
# 
se.mb.phylo <- spiec.easi(phylo, method='mb', lambda.min.ratio=1e-2,
                          nlambda=100, pulsar.params=list(rep.num=50))
# Checking fit of network, seeing if lambda.min or nlambda needs changes
se.mb.phylo$select$stars$summary
getStability(se.mb.phylo)
# Convert adjacency matrix into igraph object for analysis and plotting # 
ig.mb <- adj2igraph(getRefit(se.mb.phylo),  vertex.attr=list(name=taxa_names(phylo)))
# Isolated nodes that are not connected to any other node in the network can be removed as follows.
clean.net <- delete.vertices(net, which(degree(net, mode = "all") == 0))
## Plot network for visualization ##
plot_network(clean.net, phylo, type='taxa', color="Phyla", line_weight = 1)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!